# creating ServiceFabric-LabCluster in devtest lab using cicd pipeline

Tags: azure-devtest-labs

I am trying to create service fabric cluster in azure devtest lab for creating test environment of my service fabric application.
Can someone please provide information on creating ServiceFabric-LabCluster in devtest lab using cicd pipeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Important link which helped
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devtestlab/2018/07/11/integrate-azure-devtest-labs-environments-into-your-vsts-continuous-integration-and-delivery-pipeline/

This is the link to Public Repo: 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-devtestlab

which contains Artifacts and Envionments. Within Envronments contains ServiceFabric-LabCluster which contains azuredeploy.json from where we can get the entire information of the parameters which we need to send from VSTS Pipeline. It also contains Create-ClusterCertificate.ps1 which is used to create certificate for creating cluster.

1. So first we need to create self-signed certificate if we don't have
   one by executing this powershell file.
2. In the VSTS in new release pipeline , we have to get a task Azure
   DevTest Labs Create         Environment.
3. There we have to provide some inputs(parameters) 
          **Azure Rm subscription**: Here we select azure subscription 
          **LabName** : where we select the labname we had created 
          **Repository Name** : Here we select Public Environment Repo 
          **Template Name**: Select ServiceFabric-LabCluster 
          **Environment Name** : Here we provide Environment Name to be created 
          **Parameter** : we can provide all parameters required eg

-adminUsername '$(userName)'
-adminPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -String '$(password)' -AsPlainText -Force)
-certificate ''
-certificatePassword 'CertiicatePassword'
-certificateThumbprint ''

After creating the pipeline we deploy it and our cluster would be created in azure.